# OS X ISP bandwidth monitoring/logging

Tags: osx, networking, logs, network-monitor

I want to test my ISP speed, so I'm looking for a tool that monitors/logs internet speed so I could later look and see fluctuations.

Most tools I found so far were just bandwidth limiters.

I stumbled [NetWorx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) and [NetSpeedMonitor](http://www.floriangilles.com/software/netspeedmonitor/) for Windows, but I'm looking for an OS X tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) which has a menu item for Network with a nice bandwidth graph. Follow the link, the first screenshot will show you just that menu.

Comment: I've stumbled upon it and now I tried it, but this shows a snapshot of what's happening at the moment*, not an average speed – to determine the quality of the connection.


* similar of what can be seen with `Activity Monitor`

Answer (score 1):

Try PeakHour (AppStore: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/peakhour/id468946727?mt=12), it can connect to UPNP and SNMP routers and monitor their network interfaces directly, so you'll get a log (with shiny graphics in the menu bar) from all computers accessing the network and not just the one the logger is running on.

If you want to try if your router is supported before buying there is a "compatibility check"-App on the store too: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/peakhour-compatibility-check/id568018242?mt=12